# Flutter: I want to reboot android device from flutter app programmatically

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to reboot programmatically /Dart code or Linux script/ the android device that is running my flutter app. It's like clicking on button that is able to reboot the system.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reboot or shutdown the system from an app. In earlier versions you could use the intent:

```
"com.android.internal.intent.action.REQUEST_SHUTDOWN"
```

But this is no longer possible, only the system itself can use this intent.

Comment: What about rebooting application from itself, especially in Flutter app? Does it possible?

Comment: There seems to be a ready to use widget to use: https://github.com/Nobbas/flutter_restart

I haven't tried it, but it looks like it solves your problem.